# Client's app died... they need to cancel all recurring Android subscriptions, but I can't figure out how

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

So.. we have a client who is going out of business. Their app has a yearly recurring in-app purchase and we have around 50 people who still have it active.

On iOS I was able to just cancel the in app purchase and that immediately cancelled all of the subscriptions.

Google isn't playing nice. Once an IAP is approved it appears you can't delete it? So... how do I cancel those 50 people so they don't get renewed a year from now?

Is there a non-coding solution to this? If not... what is the coding solution?

Comment: For the users, does this subscription show up on the Google Play website (under the Subscriptions section of the Account page)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Google Play Console, you can see and cancel all subscriptions. Just open "Order Management", find the subscription and click cancel.

Comment: Hey @fjc, I can't find Order management in the Play Console: http://prntscr.com/glbq3i Am I just missing it?

Comment: You need to go to "all applications", then will see it at the bottom of the menu. It's a bit confusing that it's not per application.